# Nav. Controller Preventing Segue Transition From Animating

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue, transition

**Background:**

*My storyboard flow:*  `[Nav VC] -> [VC1] -> [Home VC] -> [Settings VC] -> ...`

I am currently using the Hero transition animation library to achieve a pull down effect (from top to bottom) when segueing from my Home VC to the Settings VC. In the storyboard have made sure to have hero enabled on my Nav, as well as the Home and Settings VC. As for the actual segue code this is what I have in the Home VC:

```
   //in Home View Controller
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "goToEditScreen") {
            let editVC = segue.destination as! ProfileMenuViewController
            //set the animation style
            editVC.hero.modalAnimationType = .selectBy(presenting: .slide(direction: .down), dismissing: .slide(direction: .up))
            editVC.documentID = self.documentID
        }
    }
```

**The Issue:**

The custom animation does not seem to be triggering, instead defaulting to the basic left to right segue. However, in the storyboard if deselect Navigation VC as the 'Initial View Controller', and instead change it to the 'VC1', then the Hero animation works (with the caveat that the Nav Bar is gone from the app).

**What I Have Tried:**

Like mentioned above I have tried switching the initial VC to not be the Nav VC and it seemed to work except I lose the nav bar. I also tried adding the same Hero code to the Settings VC in `viewDidLoad()`

```
hero.modalAnimationType = .selectBy(presenting: .slide(direction: .down), dismissing: .slide(direction: .up))
```

but to no avail, so I removed it.

If anyone has any insight into why this might be happening, please let me know!

Comment: I had the same issue! This issue needs to be solved as I couldn't see anything on SO or find much Hero documentation as well..